# Azure Function with kubernetes secret repository in Azure Container Apps

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-container-apps

I have a function app that is deployed using Azure Container Apps. Azure Functions supports several [secret repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/security-concepts?tabs=v4#secret-repositories). Since `blob` isn't really convenient for me, I'm currently using `keyvault`. This has the disadvantage that I have to provide a Key Vault only for some function keys.
As I understand it, Azure Container Apps are just based on Kubernetes and their secrets are just Kubernetes secrets. Since `kubernetes` is also a supported key store for function apps, is it possible to use it as a secret store with Azure Container Apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible currently since the app doesn't have access to create/update kubernetes secrets in ACA.

Comment: That's sad to hear. Is there any plan to implement access to ACA secrets for Function Apps?